# How to collapse / hide the "View as [Device]" panel in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I somehow ended up with this `Devices` panel: and am uncertain how to hide /collapse it:

[image]

I have looked for icons to click on, and have tried various menu options including those in the `View | Navigators`:

[image]

So what is the magic button or easter egg to hide this panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I held off on asking this question for a couple of days and finally managed to figure it out: we have to _click on the title area above the Panel that says: `View as [iPhone 11 Pro Max`:

[image]

Then it collapses the Panel down:

[image]